# Pop Up button binding strange trouble

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to using pop up button in my code.
This is how it look:[image]

This is binding configuration:
[image]

Import Choice List local attributes is array controller has reference outlets in appDelegate main code, and i update it as

```
 [tempArray setContent:carriersListArray];
```

Everything work fine, but when i select something from button, i lost one of possible choice from the list, it's moving out and leave double choosing issues:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happened, when u r using a same key name for selection and content.
To solve it just using a different key's for it.